# Jquery load content when it's on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, html-lists, lazy-loading

I have an ul list with 500 li item. It's includes title, image, description, keyword date, etc. I want to load normal only the text and keyword and load the other informations only when user scrolled to the current li element. Is there any script or javascript/jQuery code to make working this?

Comment: Google "infinite scroll"

Comment: I use live filter to the contents so I need load every data keyword and title data and later the image and description.

Comment: Also search for lazy image loading. There are lots of plugins for this.

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic for SO. We're not a replacement for Google.

Comment: Ok Sorry. I thinked you are the bests

Comment: Always good to read the how-to's, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic